# Efficient list copying

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code that works, but I'm concerned its really inefficient. Is there a more performant way of chunking/batching a list of dict's into a sort of buffer.

```
rowA = {1:"a",2:"b",3:"c"}         # Random dict
rowB = {4:"d",5:"e",6:"f"}         # Random dict
rowC = {7:"g",8:"h",9:"i"}         # Random dict
rowD = {0:"j",1:"k",2:"l"}         # Random dict
rows = [rowA ,rowB ,rowC ,rowD ]   # Add to a List
row_chunk = []                     # Empty List for buffer/cache
row_count = 0                      # Counter for buffer size
for row in rows:                          # Iterate over the list
    row_chunk.append(list(row.values()))  # Append the values from the dictionary
    row_count += 1                        # Increment the buffer size
    if row_count % 2 == 0:                # Check if the buffer reached level
        print("We have {0} dictionaries".format(len(row_chunk)))
        row_chunk = []                    # Reset the list
```

In this example, I break the list of numbers in chunks of 2. In production I expect to have chunks of 10,000 and the rows[] will have 1,000,000 entries

As mentioned this does seem to work, but feels slow and inefficient, especially appending to the list and resetting it.

Can anyone advise a better approach.

Comment: Why are you using this buffer at all?

Comment: any particular reason to use `list(row.values())`??

Comment: @BrenBarn - No particular reason. This is basically buffering writes to a database. I dont care how I break it up as long as I'm not trying to submit the whole rows[] at once.

Comment: @Copperfield Only because it seemed to work. Basically want to pull the values out of the dictionary, ignoring the keys.

Comment: @Exie: Then why not just do one "row" at a time?

Comment: @Exie in that case just `row.values()` accomplished the same thing and is quicker and memory efficient because is only a view in python 3 and can be used in most, if no all, cases if you only iterate over it

Answer (score 2):

To split a list A into two :

```
Part1=A[:len(A)/2]
Part2=A[len(A)/2:]
```

I think this is all you need :

```
>>> for row in rows:                          # Iterate over the list
...     A.append(list(row.values()))
...
>>> A=row_chunk
>>> B=A[:len(A)/2]
>>> C=A[len(A)/2:]
>>> A
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['h', 'i', 'g'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]
>>> B
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
>>> C
[['h', 'i', 'g'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]
```

**Alternative:**(by directly getting values, avoiding a loop)

```
>>> rows = [rowA.values() ,rowB.values() ,rowC.values() ,rowD.values() ]   # Add to a List
>>> rows
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['h', 'i', 'g'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]
>>> A=rows[:len(rows)/2]
>>> B=rows[len(rows)/2:]
>>> A
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
>>> B
[['h', 'i', 'g'], ['j', 'k', 'l']]
```